# Redirecting one category to another using .htacess - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to 301 Redirect one category to another category in wordpress, for some reason wordpress isn't doing it automatically so this is what i have at the moment.

```
RewriteRule ^category/?(.*)$ /free/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've tried this with no hope luck, any ideas why? been looking for a solution for 4h now and i just cant figure it out.

Looks like my 7 hours battle is over (kinda sad it took me that long) here is what worked

**Solution:**

```
RedirectMatch 301 /category/(.*) /free/$1
```

Comment: Side note: Do not test external redirects with `[R=301]`. This is a **permanent** redirect and most browsers will cache this. If you make a mistake in your rule, the browser will cache your mistake and then the browser will skip the page you are trying to redirect, instead going to the page you redirected it to before. Therefore, use `[R]` (temporary redirect) until all rules do what you want them to do.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I've been using header checkers different browsers etc still no luck? rewiterules don't need conditions right? or is there something wrong with my format?

Comment: What I understand, Wordpress uses software redirects, which might be interfering with your rule. As I have no clue about the internals of Wordpress, I can't really tell what you have to change. There might be something [between these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwordpress%5D+%5B.htaccess%5D+category) though.

Comment: thanks for taking a look at the issue, i found out the solution and updated the post. i can finnaly sleep now.

Comment: Good that it is working but usually it is not a good idea to mix `mod_rewrite` and `mod_alias` (used by RedirectMatch). WP already uses `mod_rewrite` for its internal rewrites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works using the redirectMatch rule

```
RedirectMatch 301 /category/(.*) /free/$1
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing is that your regex isn't correct since it will also match `/category-animal` also for ex. due to use of `/?` after it. Correct rule should be written like this:

```
RewriteRule ^category(/.*|)$ /free/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Moreover since WP forwards all the URIs to its `index.php` it is **important to place this rule as first rule** right below `RewriteEngine On` line or `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: I tried that, didn't seem to work, anyway i found a way using RedirectMatch 301 /category/(.*) /free/$1. Thanks for the reply.